# run wordpad print and delete tempfile in progress 4gl?

Tags: batch-file, wordpad

I have a rtf file with data and now I have created a temp file and batch file . Now how do I run wordpad print and delete tempfile in progress 4gl

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `write.exe` command line options:

```
write.exe /pt someFile.rtf "Microsoft XPS Document Writer"
```

Here the "Microsoft XPS Document Writer" printer is used. You can list available printers with `powershell "get-WmiObject -class Win32_printer | ft name, systemName, shareName"`

Answer (score 0):

You use the `OS-COMMAND` method. You can do that to invoke any os-command in any supported OS.

```
OS-COMMAND [option] VALUE("whatever command you like to run").
```

There are three different options

> **SILENT**
> After processing an operating system command, the AVM shell pauses. To exit the window in Windows GUI platforms, you must type exit. To exit the window in Windows character platforms, you must type exit and press RETURN or SPACEBAR. You can use the SILENT option to eliminate this pause. Use this option only if you are sure that the program, command, or batch file does not generate any output to the screen. Cannot be used with NO-WAIT.
>
> **NO-WAIT** In a multi-tasking environment, causes the AVM to immediately pass control back to next statement after the OS-COMMAND without waiting for the operating system command to terminate. Cannot be used with SILENT. This option is supported in Windows only.
>
> **NO-CONSOLE** While processing an operating system command, the AVM creates a console window. The console window may not be cleaned up after the command is executed. You can use the NO-CONSOLE option to prevent this window from being created in the first place.